# More oberdiek-related problems

Tags: oberdiek

When I updated MiKTeX today it stopped working because the system is still trying to find `ltxcmds.sty` and other files in the `oberdiek` package, even though we are told they have been removed from it. Adding them "on the fly" does not succeed for this reason. What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try to install the `ltxcmds` package using the MiKTeX package manager (make sure to update in both admin and user modes). It should work after that. The package was not _removed_, it is just not shipped with the `oberdiek` package, so if you have a document that needs `ltxcmds` you need to install that package.

Comment: Update the package database in user and admin mode (in the menu tasks).

Comment: Thank you. But I have done so (several times, I think) andthe system still insists on "The required file /tex/generic/oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty is missing. It is part of the following package. oberdiek… " and then obviously fails to find it.

Comment: Perhaps I am failing to understand "update in both admin and user modes". Running as administrator, I go to Tasks and update everything on offer. Should I do more than that?

Comment: I think you should also do that in the non-administrator mode, i.e. as the same user as the one trying to compile.

Comment: Thank you very much! That made a difference. The process now runs to completion, but none of the figures load, an I get an error message: "pdflatex: major issue: User/administrator updates are out-of-sync". But I always run as administrator anyway. Can that prevent things working properly?

Comment: Having looked around a bit more, I realise that I have fallen into a well-known trap for the unwary! How do I get things back into sync again? Must I reinstall MikTeX to do so?

Comment: @PeterMcClintock For a single user, it is _much_ easier to have MiKTeX installed 'just for you' in `C:\MiKTeX` or similar, _i.e._ somewhere accessible without ADmin rights

Comment: Many thanks. That is probably good advice! However our IT people prefer to use the conventional arrangement. After reinstalling MikTeX, I find that the system is still trying to extract packages from oberdiek, so maybe something needs resetting on CTAN? Loading "manually" has worked - thank goodness. An unexpected loss of half-a-day for MixTeX is annoying, but rare luckily! Thank you everyone for all your help and advice.